# Datapower - is using WAF right here?

Tags: ibm-datapower

Here's the basic scenario:

I have a set of internal machines with no public ips.  I want to front *something* in the DMZ with a public IP then forward http (and websocket) data to the internal machines.  I appreciate this may be a basic use of DataPower, but I have access to an XI52 and have been playing with it.

I'm a complete novice on DP, but I managed to configure a Web Application Firewall which would front **internal ip:port** on the DP boxes **public ip:some other port**.

However, this does not appear to allow websocket connections.  Research suggests my V7 box can do websockets but I can only see options when configuring a http front side handler, which is only available AFAK if I configure a Multi Protocol Gateway.

So - a few questions:

1 - Can you enable websockets for a WAF
2 - Is using a WAF even the right call here - how will I add in new internal machines - create a new WAF each time one is added?

Any thoughts greatly appreciated,

Sam R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSocket support is indeed introduced with v7 of the DataPower firmware. I don't have a v7 appliance available to confirm, but my understanding is that, from 7.0 onwards, you configure a multiprotocol gateway with a http front side handler, and specify that the http upgrade for web socket should be permitted. From that point on, DP will simply proxy the traffic to the configured backend.

I don't know if the WAF too supports the web socket upgrade, under 7.0, but it should be easy to verify. Under 7.1, the WAF support changes significantly - ISAM support is effectively rolled into firmware - see http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/cgi-bin/ssialias?infotype=AN&subtype=CA&htmlfid=897/ENUS214-394&appname=USN.

I think that having DP serve web socket traffic is okay *if* DP is filling a gap, or value adding by performing some other function like TLS termination or doing client authentication (i.e. password verification). Otherwise, it's a bit like killing a fly with a bazooka.